# Phonegap 2.4.0 JQuery mobile application show broken (question mark) image after using the app for a while

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a cross-platform (iOS/Android) application built using **Phonegap 2.4.0** and **jQuery Mobile 1.2.0**. Almost all the pages are added dynamically in the DOM.

The application works very well in recent mobile devices (iOS/Android) but not in older version of some Android devices. For example version **Android 2.3.0 and 4.0** have registered strange behaviour.

That is after navigating for a while in the app, all the images are replaced with question mark images and text files cannot be referenced correctly. All those files are inside the app.

Is this a problem of caching or mermory leaks?

Thanks in advance.